# The project 'My Application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method

Tags: android, gradle

I use Android studio 2.1.1 . I follow this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

This is file `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then Android studio notice:

> The project 'My Application' may be using a version of Gradle that
>   does not contain the method

[image]

I can't build project. Help me resolve problem.

Comment: post Module `build.gradle` file here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
```

from your project level `build.gradle` file and paste it in your application level `build.gradle` file.

Your application level `build.gradle` file should look something like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
//...
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
//...
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error after adding this line : impementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'  in my app level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when the Gradle version of one of the dependency is lower. So you should upgrade that dependency.

Best Idea to figure out that dependency is by disabling all the dependencies in application and project level Gradle unless you stop getting the same error and then keep adding dependency one by one unless you get the error.

In your case culprit is **'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'**.
So just upgrade cardview library to latest.